# Can we deploy python REST API application on Apache tomcat Server

Tags: python-3.x, web-deployment, tomcat8

I developed REST API in PYTHON. I want to deploy it on Apache Tomcat Server,
Is it possible to deploy it on Tomcat server?

Comment: why would you like to do this horrible horrible thing?

Comment: I am just confirming weather is it possible or not?

Comment: @shahaf which server can be use for REST API deployment?

Comment: any language has its own servers, java has tomcat, undertow, jetty and a few more, python has flask, Django, tornado and also some more, I suggest go with python and flask http://flask.pocoo.org/ (easier for beginner) despite your tomcat8 tag

Comment: Sometimes requirements seem strange, but I only have Permission to run Tomcat and it would be good if I could lanch a Python program. This question is valid. Maybe use Jython and modjy?